# GMSMarker not aligned to a user

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I got some issue with my GMSMarker it seems its not properly aligned to user. See image below: marker doesn't aligned

[image]

How can I align the center to the user location perspective?

Code below:

```
self.contractorMarker.iconView = self.markerImageView(image: UIImage(named: "contractor-marker")!, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
                                CATransaction.begin()
                                CAAnimation.init().duration = 0.5
                                self.contractorMarker.position = contractorCoordinate
                                CATransaction.commit()
                                self.contractorMarker.map = self.mapView
```

Comment: Question should be asked with relevant  code

Comment: will do @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: @AlvinQuezon set groundAnchor = CGPoint (0.5,0.5)

Comment: Hi @chiragshah yeah great help! thanks for this, and anyway, could you please answer this question so others will aware of this?  I will vote your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinQuezon sure let me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with groundAnchor property

```
self.contractorMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x:0.5, y: 0.5)
```

Comment: @AlvinQuezon is possible please upvote and accept the answer